# Thread - JDK0.1 - getting error when I check [this != currentThread()]

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

so I need to check if I am not in the same thread of 'main' using [this != currentThread()] to check that.
behaviour: extending thread and implementing Runnable will behave differently. why?

Why when I extend a thread this code will run:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        MyThread a = new MyThread();
        a.start();
        a.run();
    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (this != currentThread()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("run() must not be called directly");
            }
            System.out.println(getName() + " run started...");
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            System.out.println('\n' + getName() + " run ended.");
        }
    }
}
```

However when I implement Runnable, I get an error - code:

```
import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThreadRunnable());


        t1.start();
//        t1.run();
    }

    private static class MyThreadRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (this != currentThread()) {  // I get an error here 
                throw new IllegalStateException("run() must not be called directly");
            }
            Thread thread = currentThread();
            System.out.println(thread.getName() + " run started...");
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            System.out.println('\n' + thread.getName() + " run ended.");
        }
    }
}
```

what I am missing?

Comment: `Thread` has the method `currentThread()` `Runnable` don't.

Comment: @seenukarthi to OP has `import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;` and can therefore call `currentThread()` in the second example too.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example `MyThreadRunnable` does not extend `Thread`. `Thread.currentThread()` only returns `Thread` instances (i.e. instances of `java.lang.Thread` or instances of subclasses of `java.lang.Thread`).

The Java Language specification say about this case [15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).

Since you cannot cast `MyThreadRunnable` to `Thread` nor cast `Thread` to `MyThreadRunnable` (both would throw a `ClassCastException`) this rule applies.

You could add a cast to `Runnable` to make it compile:

```
if ((Runnable) this != currentThread()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("run() must not be called directly");
}
```

But this would always throw the `IllegalStateException` because `this` can never be a `Thread` instance.

Comment: straight to the point. Danke!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    MyThreadRunnable r1 = new MyThreadRunnable();
    
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    
    r1.setMyThread(t1);


    t1.start();
    t1.run();
}

private static class MyThreadRunnable implements Runnable {
    
    private Thread thread;

    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        if (thread != Thread.currentThread()) {  // I get an error here 
            throw new IllegalStateException("run() must not be called directly");
        }
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(thread.getName() + " run started...");
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println('\n' + thread.getName() + " run ended.");
    }



    public void setMyThread(Thread t1) {
        this.thread = t1;
    }
}
```

edit:
First of all, currentThread():Thread is called statically by Thread. In your first example, you inherit from Thread, which is why the compiler recognizes this.

Secondly, Runnable is not a thread. Therefore, you cannot compare this with Thread.currentThread(). You can set the thread with the setter before you try to start it.